# Dual supply source, how to do the switching?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, circuit-protection

I'm designing a circuit that I'd like to normally power from a 12-36VDC source, but want to have the option of also powering it via the USB connection during configuration.

I've chosen the [LMR16030](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16030.pdf) for the regulator via the TI "PowerBench" designer. This regulator works with a 4.3-60V input and is set up to regulate a constant 3.3V output to power the microcontroller (a [PIC32MZ2048EFM144](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32MZ-EF-%20Family-DS60001320F.pdf)).

Originally I had thought of just using a diode, but because `VIN` can be 12-36V I didn't want to reverse-bias and conduct back into the USB port, and additionally the forward voltage drop was too much (can't be more than 700mV before the regulator goes into low-voltage shutdown).

So I decided to come up with the same reverse-voltage that I use on the `VIN` line for the `VUSB` line. What I'm not sure of is if this will work when both supplies are connected, especially if the `VIN` is removed if the regulator will drop out or not?

[image]

(Don't mind the symbol for the SI4447ADY-T1-GE3, I'll change it to a standard P-Channel Mosfet soon. Q1 is also a P-Channel Mosfet).

There should be enough bulk-capacitance on the input side to make any transition bump-less, but I haven't designed a dual-input supply before and would like to know if I'm hitting my mark or not?

The goal here is to be able to plug/unplug one supply source or the other without the 3.3V output turning off. I understand I'll have to do some power negotiation with the USB host to get full power but having the full 3A power output from the regulator from USB input is not a design criteria.

Edit: Here are the design specifications:

- 12-36VDC Normal Input Voltage
- 5VDC Input Voltage via USB during Configuration
- 3.3V @ 3A Output Voltage
- Industrial Temperature Range up to maximum operating temp of 120°C
- Output of 3.3V @ 1A when connected to USB
- VUSB power may be removed while VIN is connected without resetting device
- VIN power may be removed while VUSB is connected without resetting device

I won't put the microcontroller side requirements because I don't think they are relevant here, but if there is something specific I'm missing I'll add it in. I'll be shutting peripherals down when VUSB is connected to avoid drawing more than 1A from the power supply. I'm not concerned too much about efficiency because this is not battery powered, but it should be in the 85%+ range when connected to normal power.

Comment: Can you list all your design specs and which one is an issue? You may left some out.  Ideal FET diode and Sch. diodes are some options. Compute your Cutoff Vin vs Iout.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I've added some of the design specs, I've looked at the cut-off Vin vs Iout from the data sheet and it seems I'm well within specs @ 5V for a 1A Iout unless I'm misreading it.

Comment: OK so as long as the cutout specs enable a smooth internal  or external diode switch, you are OK, But I didn't see specs for this.